# How to access the value of a Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup object within a form?

Tags: forms, 8

I tried this : `dpm($button['#value']->string`
but got this error:
 access protected property Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup::$string

Within a form object I need to be able to read that value and also change it.  how can I access it? 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By casting the object to a (string), you will get the value.

Example:

```
$op = (string) $form_state->getValue('op');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the string value by calling the magic function `->__tostring()` or casting the object to a `(string)`. But most time you don't need to do this, because if you use the translation object in a string context it will return the translated string automatically.

You can't change the original string in the translation object. You have to generate a new one with the t-function:

```
$button['#value'] = $this->t('new text');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the string value by using the following method.

```
getUntranslatedString()
```

So if you get the object as $link_object then accessing the string would be done using

```
$link_object->getUntranslatedString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is a combiantion of the answers of @yash-khandelwal and @binny.

`$form_state->getValue('op')->getUntranslatedString();`